# pandas shifts column names and fills last column with NAN

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file that is tab delimited.

```
Example:
Rec#    Cyc#    Step    Test (Sec)  Step (Sec)  Amp-hr  Watt-hr Amps    Volts   State   ES  DPt Time
1   0   1   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  3.41214609  R   0   09:44:13    
2   0   1   30.00000000 30.00000000 0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  3.41077280  R   1   09:44:43    
3   0   1   60.00000000 60.00000000 0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  3.41077280  R   1   09:45:13
```

I read the csv in using:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', sep='\t')
```

This gives the output:

```
    Rec#  Cyc#     Step  Test (Sec)  Step (Sec)    Amp-hr   Watt-hr      Amps  Volts  State      ES  DPt Time
1      0     1     0.00        0.00    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  3.412146   R      0  09:44:13       NaN
2      0     1    30.00       30.00    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  3.410773   R      1  09:44:43       NaN
3      0     1    60.00       60.00    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  3.410773   R      1  09:45:13       NaN
```

This seems to have shifted my column names over by one and causes my last column to be filled with NAN's instead of dates.

If I do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("foo.csv", sep="\t")
df = pd.read_csv("foo.csv", sep="\t", usecols=df[:len(df.columns)])
```

I get the following output:

```
    Rec#  Cyc#   Step  Test (Sec)  Step (Sec) Amp-hr   Watt-hr      Amps  Volts  State    ES  DPt Time
1   1      0     1     0.00        0.00    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  3.412146   R      0  09:44:13
2   2      0     1    30.00       30.00    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  3.410773   R      1  09:44:43
3   3      0     1    60.00       60.00    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  3.410773   R      1  09:45:13
```

Also if I try to just grab two specific columns it seems to grab those correctly.  As in df = df = pd.read_csv("foo.csv", sep="\t", usecols=[3, 8]) will correctly grab the Time (Sec) column and the Volts Column.

I was hoping there was a way to correctly frame the data that wouldn't require me reading it twice.

Thanks in advance!

Oniwa

Comment: Can you post a link to the raw txt file, it's likely that perhaps there are more tabs than you expect

Comment: @EdChum I would if it wasn't a work file.  Looking at it in Notepad++ it looks like there are trailing tabs at the end of each line.  DSM found the same thing in the answer below and found a solution that works.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like there are some trailing tabs:

```
>>> with open("oniwa.dat") as fp:
...     for line in fp:
...         print(repr(line))
...         
'Rec#\tCyc#\tStep\tTest (Sec)\tStep (Sec)\tAmp-hr\tWatt-hr\tAmps\tVolts\tState\tES\tDPt Time\n'
'1\t0\t1\t0.00000000\t0.00000000\t0.00000000\t0.00000000\t0.00000000\t3.41214609\tR\t0\t09:44:13\t\n'
'2\t0\t1\t30.00000000\t30.00000000\t0.00000000\t0.00000000\t0.00000000\t3.41077280\tR\t1\t09:44:43\t\n'
'3\t0\t1\t60.00000000\t60.00000000\t0.00000000\t0.00000000\t0.00000000\t3.41077280\tR\t1\t09:45:13\n'
```

As a result, pandas concludes there's an index column.  We can tell it otherwise using `index_col`.  To be specific, instead of

```
>>> pd.read_csv("oniwa.dat", sep="\t") # no good
   Rec#  Cyc#  Step  Test (Sec)  Step (Sec)  Amp-hr  Watt-hr      Amps Volts  \
1     0     1     0           0           0       0        0  3.412146     R   
2     0     1    30          30           0       0        0  3.410773     R   
3     0     1    60          60           0       0        0  3.410773     R   

   State        ES  DPt Time  
1      0  09:44:13       NaN  
2      1  09:44:43       NaN  
3      1  09:45:13       NaN
```

we can use

```
>>> pd.read_csv("oniwa.dat", sep="\t", index_col=False) # hooray!
   Rec#  Cyc#  Step  Test (Sec)  Step (Sec)  Amp-hr  Watt-hr  Amps     Volts  \
0     1     0     1           0           0       0        0     0  3.412146   
1     2     0     1          30          30       0        0     0  3.410773   
2     3     0     1          60          60       0        0     0  3.410773   

  State  ES  DPt Time  
0     R   0  09:44:13  
1     R   1  09:44:43  
2     R   1  09:45:13
```